# To maintain the state of a scrolling level menu

Tags: objective-c, xcode, menu, cocos2d-iphone

Iam working on a game in which I have created a horizontal scrolling menu for levels using CCScrollLayer.
On that menu I have added a back button which when pressed takes the user to main menu.
What I want is: I want to maintain the state of the level menu when user comes back to the level selection screen. 
Heres what Iam doing:

```
CCScrollLayer * scrolllayer = [[CCScrollLayer alloc] initWithLayers:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:layer1,layer2,layer3, nil] widthOffset:230];

//scrolllayer.showPagesIndicator = YES;

[self addChild:scrolllayer z:0];
```

I have created a scrollLayer and added a back button on it. Suppose user is playing level No.3 and presses the back button to go to main menu. After that if user goes back to level selection screen then the level 3 should come on the screen. The menu should not show the levels from the beginning.

Thanks for your time.

Regards

Shailesh

Comment: I guess you used a specific programming language? Do you mind to add this please? Or do you mean CSS? THen please add this tag.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Thanks for reply.. well Iam working on a iPhone game.So Iam using Objective C and xcode with Cocos2d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain the level number any where... And use this method

```
-(void) moveToPage:(int)page;
```

The scroller will move to that level...

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: @ Nikhil Aneja: Thanks for reply.. But can u please explain me in some more depth..? I have created my 3 layers and added them in scrollLayer in INIT function itself. Also do I need to use Arrays?

Comment: No.. in your level scene.. write this code..

scroller = [[CCScrollLayer alloc] initWithLayers:tempLayerArray widthOffset: 10];

[self addChild:scroller];

[scroller moveToPage:[appDelegate scrollerEntered]];

This scrollerEntered is your variable for initial page... Initially its 0. Once you enter a level. assign to to level number... It will work fine.. :)